# ClipPath and SVG Scaling

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to get a scaled svg image to clip the pattern if it goes out side the blue container. But when I apply the clip path to the pattern for the exact same position. The pattern's X and Y position change and it ends up outside the container in the case shown below for the exact same positions and transformations applied. I also applied a feMorphology filter to show where the clipped path is being drawn.

**SVG** (Non clipped)

[image: Non Clipped]

**XML**

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1006" width="550" height="650" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs">
    <defs id="SvgjsDefs1007">
        <clipPath id="SvgjsClipPath1019">
            <rect id="SvgjsRect1016" width="315" height="600" x="120" y="27"></rect>
        </clipPath>
        <filter id="dilate_shape">
            <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceGraphic" radius="5" />
        </filter>
    </defs><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?-->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="550" height="650" viewBox="0 0 550 650" xml:space="preserve">
        <g >
            <g filter="url(&quot;#dilate_shape&quot;)">
                <rect width="315" height="600" x="120" y="27" fill="blue" fill-opacity="0.2" clip-path="url(&quot;#SvgjsClipPath1019&quot;)"></rect>
            </g>
            <image xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/pri/get/697%20%5BConverted%5D.svg?_subject_uid=360738345&amp;raw=1&amp;size=1280x960&amp;size_mode=3&amp;w=AADJZ7-5-jq5Qyh2urbHo_G1FCn0ADHB-Li1KOFGuAEEQQ" transform="translate(278.34 410.34) scale(1.66 1.66)"  x="-75" y="-75" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="150" height="150"  ></image>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

**SVG** (Clipped)

[image: Clipped]

**XML**

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1006" width="550" height="650" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs">
    <defs id="SvgjsDefs1007">
        <clipPath id="SvgjsClipPath1019">
            <rect id="SvgjsRect1016" width="315" height="600" x="120" y="27"></rect>
        </clipPath>
        <filter id="dilate_shape">
            <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceGraphic" radius="5" />
        </filter>
    </defs><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?-->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="550" height="650" viewBox="0 0 550 650" xml:space="preserve">
        <g >
            <g filter="url(&quot;#dilate_shape&quot;)">
                <rect width="315" height="600" x="120" y="27" fill="blue" fill-opacity="0.2" clip-path="url(&quot;#SvgjsClipPath1019&quot;)"></rect>
            </g>
            <image xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/pri/get/697%20%5BConverted%5D.svg?_subject_uid=360738345&amp;raw=1&amp;size=1280x960&amp;size_mode=3&amp;w=AADJZ7-5-jq5Qyh2urbHo_G1FCn0ADHB-Li1KOFGuAEEQQ" transform="translate(278.34 410.34) scale(1.66 1.66)"  x="-75" y="-75" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="150" height="150"  clip-path="url(&quot;#SvgjsClipPath1019&quot;)"></image>
        </g>
   </svg>
```

With the only difference being is that I added **clip-path="url("#SvgjsClipPath1019")**" to the image tag of the second svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in the order in which the `transform` and `clip-path` attributes are applied. `transform` is always the last operation, and the `clip-path` is applied to the non-transformed element.

This snippet

```
<image xlink:href="..." x="-75" y="-75"
       transform="translate(278.34 410.34) scale(1.66 1.66)"
       clip-path="url(#SvgjsClipPath1019)" />
```

is equivalent to

```
<g transform="translate(278.34 410.34) scale(1.66 1.66)">
    <image xlink:href="..." x="-75" y="-75"
           clip-path="url(#SvgjsClipPath1019)" />
</g>
```

while you wanted to achieve this:

```
<g clip-path="url(#SvgjsClipPath1019)">
    <image xlink:href="..." x="-75" y="-75"
       transform="translate(278.34 410.34) scale(1.66 1.66)"> />
</g>
```